# How to write callback for newly added element in DOM upon click action in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a button which adds new element to DOM. Now I want to write event listner for click on this new Element. But not able to do so because when page loads this element will not be in DOM. The code I have tried so far is

```
    const initButton = document.querySelector(".wS .amr .amn .ams");
    initButton.click() // this will add new element in DOM which will be async action

    // now I want to perform following on newly added element
    
    document.querySelector(".fX.aXjCH").setAttribute("style", "display:block");
    document.querySelector(".aB.gQ.pE").click();
```

I need some callback mechanism so that I can execute the later code once the DOM is updated with new component. How can I achieve this? how can I make assure the DOM is updated? or is there any way I can write callback for the first click()?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have the script tag just before the end body tag
2. Add `readystatechange` event like this -
3. after the append yo can access the newly added markup.

Note: this kind of appending child using in `.innerHTML` is not safe if the markup is coming from say a Database and can cause XSS unless we sanitize the `str`.

```html
<body>
<ul id="ul_o">
<button class='wS amr amn ams'>WS </button>
<div class='container'>

</div>
</ul>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    const initButton = document.querySelector(".wS.amr.amn.ams");
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    initButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
      
      var str = '<p>something here</p>';
      var temp = document.createElement('div');
      temp.innerHTML = str;
      container.appendChild(temp);
   const span = document.querySelector("p");
      console.log(span);
    });
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```